# PHP - Pass named function to another function

Tags: php

I have a function `collectRows` that accepts a sqli_result object, and returns the query results as a array of rows:

```
function collectRows($result) {
    ...
}
```

and have another function that accepts a function to decide what to do with the query results before returning them:

```
function execQuery($query, $resultsF=null) {
    ...    
}
```

I want to use `execQuery` like so:

```
execQuery("SELECT * FROM...", collectRows);
```

But I get complaints that it can't find the constant "collectRows".

Obviously, I could do something like:

```
execQuery("SELECT * FROM...", function($result) {
    return collectRows($result);
});
```

But it would be nice to be able to write it a more succinctly.

Is there a way to pass a named function without wrapping it in an anonymous function?

Comment: Read about PHP [callables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: There's a special callable type. Read more about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function name instead of function itself should be passed to a function:

```
function execQuery($query, $functionName=null) {
    if (is_callable($functionName)) {
        $functionName();
    }
}
```

And call it:

```
execQuery("SELECT * FROM...", 'collectRows');
```

More info about [callable type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: Oh, that's weird. I can just call a string and it will look up the function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, you only have to pass the name as a string. PHP doesn't care, it'll deal with it anyway.